# C# Creating Multiple work sheet from multiple thread throwing error root level is invalid

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus to generate excel file with multiple sheets.I am trying to add multiple worksheet to a single excel file from different thread and getting ambiguous error message **root level is invalid**

Here is my code. please some one have look and tell me what i am doing wrong in my code ?

```
ExcelPackage excelPackage = null;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string exclpath = @"d:\Test1.xlsx";

    FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@exclpath);
    excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi);

    Action[] actions;

    actions = new Action[]
    {
        () => Test1(),
        () => Test2()
    };

    Parallel.Invoke(actions);
    excelPackage.Save();
}

private void Test1()
{
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Delta");
    ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test Delta";
}

private void Test2()
{
    OfficeOpenXml.ExcelWorksheet ws = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Horizontal");
    ws.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Test Horizontal";
}
```

Please guide me how can i add multiple sheets with data from different thread into single excel file.
is it not possible ?

if possible please guide me. Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure Excel uses [single-threaded apartment model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/single-threaded-apartments) for its COM services (which is everything you need to create a worksheet). You can't do it from multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on similar requirement recently and the way I handled is given below,

1. Create a separate class to hold the results. As Each method produces different type of list object, I added a property of type IList.

   ```
    public class SearchResult
    {
        public IList Result { get; set; } 
    }
   ```
2. Now, use parallel invoke to get results, create a separate instance of SearchResult class, set the response to Result property

   ```
    private static void CreateReport(List<RawData> rawDataList)
    {
        var resultList = new List<SearchResult>();

        Parallel.Invoke(
            () =>
            {
                var result = new SearchResult();
                result.Result = SearchStudent(rawDataList); 
                resultList.Add(result);
            },
            () =>
            {
                var result = new SearchResult();
                result.Result = SearchStaff(rawDataList);
                resultList.Add(result);
            }
        );

        ExcelWriter.CreateReport(resultList);
    }
   ```
3. Now you have a resultlist with different type of results. I want to add them in separate sheet and generate the excel file.

   ```
    public static void CreateReport(List<SearchResult> searchResults)
    {
        using (var xlpackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            foreach(var searchResult in searchResults)
            {
                if (searchResult.Result?.Count == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var resultType = searchResult.Result[0].GetType();
                var worksheet = xlpackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(resultType.Name);
                var columnNames = Helper.GetPropertiesNames(Activator.CreateInstance(resultType)).ToList();

                int colNumber = 1;
                foreach (var columnName in columnNames)
                {
                    worksheet.Cells[1, colNumber++].Value = columnName;
                }

                int rowNumber = 1;
                foreach (var data in searchResult.Result)
                {
                    //fill the cells, format as per requirement
                }
            }

            var fileName = "Demo.xlsx";
            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(Config.ReportLoc, fileName));
            xlpackage.SaveAs(fileInfo);
        }
    }
   ```

I hope this helps/provides idea for your requirement.

Comment: Now that's just not thread-safe. You can't add to the same list from different threads without some form of syncronization.

Comment: Had you written the first `CreateReport` as `private static void CreateReport(List<RawData> rawDataList) { ExcelWriter.CreateReport(rawDataList.AsParallel().Select(x => new SearchResult()).AsSequential().ToList()); }` it would have been better.

Comment: It would be even better if you didn't chain off to `ExcelWriter.CreateReport`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, thank you for the suggestions. I will see if I can improve the code based on your suggestions. I did not get your message "It would be even better if you didn't chain off to ExcelWriter.CreateReport". It will be helpful if you could elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: Your `static void CreateReport(List<RawData> rawDataList)` method calls `ExcelWriter.CreateReport(resultList);` at the end - it is chaining off to that method. Instead it's better for the first signature to be `static List<SearchResult> GenerateSearchResults(List<RawData> rawDataList)` and make it a stand-alone method. The calling code would then do the chaining of the methods. This allows you to test your method and to more easily understand the flow. It makes for more maintainable code.

Comment: @Enigmativity sure, thank you.